# Git clone Angular Cli project show that you are not in the project

Tags: angular-cli, cloning

I've been always struggling with angular cli as it keeps giving me the error that I am not in angular cli project .

Would like to setup this project https://github.com/codediodeio/ngrx-fire.

```
I followed the basics:
git clone https://github.com/codediodeio/ngrx-fire.git ngrxFire
cd ngrxFire
npm install
```

and than ng serve, show me that I am not in the project and I am 100%. 
Is there a configuration on my machine I normally need to update when i am doing a angular cli project?

Comment: Have you created `src/environments/environment.ts` file? By the way, please provide the exact error you get.

Comment: yes I have and I have figured how to get this running, will post in a second

Comment: what is your global angular cli version?

Comment: Latest , always try use the latest when I get into trouble with code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to set it up, not sure if this is how you do it and what is the issue but it worked. One of these days:

So you do the usual:

```
git clone https://github.com/codediodeio/ngrx-fire.git ngrxFire

cd ngrxFire
```

**but than you**

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
npm install
npm init
```

On ng init say no to NOT overwrite anything, the next issue it will scream is that something with promise and polyfill so you need to run a command:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```

You will notice that it create an enviorments folder in the root of the app, so in the module.ts re-point it to the right folder.

Than you will need to in firebase do two things:
1) Change the setting in Authentication so that Anonymous user can connect and change the rules in the db  to

```
{
    "rules": {    
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Than you can run ng-serve. Now why this work , if anyone could explain I would buy that persona a drink. Why does angular-cli conflict like this?

Answer (score 3):

Before running `npm install` please do the following:

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install -g npm
```

then

```
$ npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no command as `ng init` . Can you please confirm the steps you followed.
Output from `ng init`:

`The specified command init is invalid. For available options, see ng help.`